# Confused about when to use the @client directive and different ways to access the Apollo cache

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I've created an apollo server and am now working on the front end side of things. My current stack is Nuxtjs/Nuxt-apollo/Apollo-server and am opting to use Apollo's cache for local state management instead of vuex.

I've been able to connect to the apollo server that I've made, ran queries and mutations on the server and by cache. However, I'm very confused as to when I should be using the *@client* directive. I think this is more of a case of me not being able to see the bigger picture so I'll break down my thought process.

1) You run a query/mutation and that gets put into the browser cache.

2) You can now access that query/mutation from cache and run it without having to make a call to the server with client.readQuery and writeQuery. (I'm probably already not understanding this correctly as I'm reading the official docs.)

3)The @client directive is to manage state and you place this beside any field that you want to be cached. This also only reaches out to cache and local resolvers only.. are these custom? But from my experience it looks as if this overwrites ROOT_QUERY, ROOT_MUTATION inside of the cache? That seems a little counter-intuitive?

To make my question more specific and less vague, ***when*** should I be using readQuery/writeQuery/readFragment/writeFragment and the @client directive. If possible as laymanized as possible?